# retrieve multiple data value from different tables using JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql-query-store

I have three table. 
1. bni_category
2. bni_chapter
3. bni_member

```
CREATE TABLE `bni_category` (
 `bni_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `bni_category_name` text,
 `is_active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `is_delete` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `last_update` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `bni_chapter_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
 create_date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`bni_category_id`),
 KEY `bni_chapter_id` (`bni_chapter_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `bni_category_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`bni_chapter_id`) 
REFERENCES `bni_chapter` (`bni_chapter_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

BNI_chapter

```
CREATE TABLE `bni_chapter` (
 `bni_chapter_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `bni_chapter_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `create_date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`is_delete` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `last_update` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`bni_chapter_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

BNI_member

```
 CREATE TABLE `bni_member` (
`bni_member_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `bni_member_name` text,
 `bni_member_mobile` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
 `bni_member_email` text,
 `bni_member_website` text,
 `bni_member_bio` text,
 `bni_member_export_to` text,
 `bni_member_import_from` text,
 `bni_member_want_to_connect_to` text,
 `bni_member_company` text,
 `bni_chapter_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `bni_category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `bni_member_address` text,
 `bni_member_commitee` text,
 `bni_member_profilepic` longblob NOT NULL,
 `bni_member_logo` longblob NOT NULL,
 `create_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `is_active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `is_delete` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `last_update` text,
 `del_status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`bni_member_id`),
 KEY `bni_chapter_id` (`bni_chapter_id`),
 KEY `bni_category_id` (`bni_category_id`),
  KEY `bni_member_id` (`bni_member_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `bni_member_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`bni_chapter_id`) REFERENCES 
`bni_chapter` (`bni_chapter_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `bni_member_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`bni_category_id`) 
REFERENCES `bni_category` (`bni_category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=223 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Now I want to display
bni_member_name
bni_member_id
bni_chapter_id
bni_chapter_name
bni_category_id
bni_category_name FROM bni_member and chapter id, and chapter name form chapter table and category id, category name form category table.

final table should be looklike

```
Member Id | Member Name | Chapter Id | Chapter Name | Category Id 
|category Name
```

Comment: Have you tried any Query using Joins?

Comment: Yes, I used Cross Join. @user1309690

Comment: Can you please show your query and what output you are getting using that.

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM bni_member CROSS JOIN bni_chapter CROSS JOIN 
    bni_category WHERE bni_member_id = '".$_POST["employee_id"]."'";`                            But it gives same data again and again. @user1309690

Comment: But I don't think it is working. it giving wrong data. Can you please help..@user1309690

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following query.

```
SELECT A.bni_member_id, A.bni_member_name, A.bni_chapter_id, B.bni_chapter_name,  A.bni_category_id, C.bni_category_name FROM `bni_member` AS a LEFT JOIN `bni_chapter` as B on A.bni_chapter_id = B.bni_chapter_id left join `bni_category` AS C on A.bni_category_id = C.bni_category_id
```